# (RockyLinux+PHP+Apache) Getting 503 Service Unavailable Error

Tags: php, docker, apache, dockerfile

I hope everyone is doing well.
I have created a Rocky Linux container that includes PHP and Apache. I run the image with `:8080` port open. Whenever I try to reach the web server from a web browser by going into `localhost:8080` I get `503 Service Unavailable - The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.` error. I couldn't figure what to do next. How can I solve this issue? Thanks!

This is my Dockerfile:

````
RUN dnf update -y
RUN dnf install httpd -y
RUN dnf install php -y
RUN dnf install procps -y
RUN dnf install net-tools -y
RUN dnf install findutils -y
RUN dnf install vim -y
RUN dnf install git -y
RUN mkdir /run/php-fpm
ADD index.php /var/www/html/
CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND```
````

Answer (score 0):

"On RHEL 8/Rocky Linux 8, [mod_php] has been Deprecated and PHP-FPM (FPM : FastCGI Process Manager) is configured by default."

Check to see if the php-fpm service is running. If its not by default (which it most likely is not) you can modify the Dockerfile to also start php-fpm

In your `Dockerfile` try something like:

```
CMD php-fpm -D; /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```